# Show that any two vertexes in a Rado graph can be connected by a path of length 10.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that any two vertexes in a Rado graph can be connected by a path of length 10.
I am thinking about the induced subgraph of a rado graph.

Comment: Given that it's a random graph, I doubt the statement is true.

Comment: @CalvinLin Why is it a random graph? It is isomorphic to a random graph with probability $1$, but still it has a definition as non-random graph, right?